# Убрать помехи бинарное изображение C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, изображения, qtcreator

Превращаю изображение в бинарное(черно-белое):

```
image = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Mono);
```

Получается вот такое изображение с помехами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А необходимо, что получилось примерно вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать помехи, желательно без сторонних библиотек?

Comment: `convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Mono, Qt::ThresholdDither);` не?

Comment: Гениально и просто)

Comment: Оформите как ответ, пожалуйста)

Comment: добавь в ответ итоговое изображение, если не лень...

Comment: Ну то есть вопрос криво сформулирован: никаких "помех" на самом деле не было, а все "помехи" автор сгенерировал сам, запросив дизеринг при конвертации изображения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
image = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Mono, Qt::ThresholdDither);
```

Фглаг `Qt::ThresholdDither` отключает [дизеринг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) и применяет простой пороговый алгоритм для конвертации изображения.

см [`QImage::convertToFormat()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#convertToFormat), [`Qt::ImageConversionFlag`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ImageConversionFlag-enum)

Полученное изображение:

[image: Обесцвеченное око тьмы взирает тебе в душу своим пустым зрачком]

Comment: Если в изображении пиксели ближе к черным, например такое - https://imgur.com/vfRpN5p
То оно ставиться полностью черным. Можно как то настроить данный метод?
Чтобы если помех нету, то не трогать его?

Comment: @Optimus, судя по API не похоже... всё же Qt — это не что-то серьёзное для обработки графики... но там ручками набросать — нечего делать: цикл по всем пикселям и сравнение с пороговым значением...

Comment: Пороговое значение? Я с обработкой графики только недавно начал работать. Принцип понимаю. Не могли бы вы подробнее описать?

Comment: @Optimus, да, в самом простом варианте, просто берёшь константу (или предлагаешь пользователю ввести), например `128`. потом все пиксели, которые темнее делаешь чёрным, а все, что светлее — белым.... так собственно Qt работает в алгоритме из ответа... в более сложном варианте можно вычислит эту константу, например как медиану или среднее значение яркости; или «среднее значение не слишком тусклых пикселей»..